# Make functional functions OO functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Let's say I have this easy `id` function:

```
let id = a => a
```

And now I want to make it a OO-style method, without redefining it, i.e.

```
let a = {foo:5}
a.id()  // {foo:5}
```

How can I turn the first function into the second? Is there some hack to do this? I tried working with `bind`, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you asking how to put a function on every object? Don't do that.

Comment: This feels like an X/Y problem. You need to do X, think Y is the way to do it, and have asked about Y. What's X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To transform a normal function `id` into a function that implicitly depends on a receiver (referenced by `this`) you need to assign an auxiliary function to your prototype:

```js
class Cons {
  constructor(x) { this.foo = x }
  asMethod(f) { return (...args) => f(this, ...args) }
}

const o = new Cons(5);
const id = x => x;

console.log(
  o.asMethod(id) ()
);
```

This doesn't make much sense though! Your functions would have to expect the receiver as their first argument and hence were quite specific, which is the opposite of generic. That `id` works in the example is just a coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do it with `bind`:

```
let id = a => a;
// ...
let a = {foo:5};
a.id = id.bind(null, a);
a.id(); // {foo:5}
```

Technically, though, `bind` returns a new function.

---

I think you ruled this out, but alternately, of course, just define another arrow:

```
a.id = _ => id(a);
```

or a non-arrow

```
a.id = function() { return id(this); };
```

...although that one's dependent on how it's called.